# Mysql match on two columns and get count

Tags: mysql, count

How do I get a count of?

```
+---------+-------------+
|   col1  |   col2      |  
+---------+-------------+
|     Joe | April       |
|    Fred | May         |
|     Sam | April       | 
|     Joe | April       |
|    Mark | Jan         | 
|     Joe | Dec         |             
+---------+-------------+
```

In MYSQL how do I get a count on Names that match only if Month also match?
IE 
Joe    April should be only one...

Comment: I hope count of Joe April should be 2.

Answer (score 4):

[**@Abdul's answer**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55607/877) just needs `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

The query shold look like this now

```
SELECT COUNT(*), col1 , col2 FROM test GROUP BY col1,col2 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Here is the execution of it:

```
mysql> create table test(col1 varchar(20),col2 varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.33 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test VALUES('Joe','April'),('Fred','May'),
    -> ('Sam','April'),('Joe','April'),('Mark','Jan'),('Joe','Dec');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT COUNT(*), col1 , col2 FROM test GROUP BY col1,col2 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
+----------+------+-------+
| COUNT(*) | col1 | col2  |
+----------+------+-------+
|        2 | Joe  | April |
+----------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.24 sec)

mysql>
```

If you do not care for the count, remove it from the SELECT clause

```
mysql> SELECT col1 , col2 FROM test GROUP BY col1,col2 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
+------+-------+
| col1 | col2  |
+------+-------+
| Joe  | April |
+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a table and insert records

```
create table test(col1 varchar(20),col2 varchar(20));

INSERT INTO test VALUES('Joe','April'),('Fred','May'),('Sam','April'),('Joe','April'),('Mark','Jan'),('Joe','Dec');

SELECT * FROM test;
+------+-------+
| col1 | col2  |
+------+-------+
| Joe  | April |
| Fred | May   |
| Sam  | April |
| Joe  | April |
| Mark | Jan   |
| Joe  | Dec   |
+------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Find actual result**

```
SELECT COUNT(*), col1 , col2 FROM test GROUP BY col1,col2;
+----------+------+-------+
| COUNT(*) | col1 | col2  |
+----------+------+-------+
|        1 | Fred | May   |
|        2 | Joe  | April |
|        1 | Joe  | Dec   |
|        1 | Mark | Jan   |
|        1 | Sam  | April |
+----------+------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Does not work always return 1 Joe and April should return 2

Comment: I hope you are intended to return 1 as in your example you said that Joe April should be 1 but Joe April are two times in table.

Comment: Joe April should be 2

Comment: Updated My Answer.